# Fail on using 2 Transistor as a Switch

Tags: transistors, switches, switching

Now I'm trying to design a circuit which have 2 voltage level (12V and 3.3V). What I want to create is simple switch using 3.3V to turn off 12V. I know there are thousand question about transistor on this site, but after spending some time scrolling, I haven't found what I wanted.

So far, this is what I have designed and simulate it on Proteus.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2farl8k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question is, do I have a wrong circuit? or perhaps the Proteus simulator is not correct? Thanks in advance. Please ask if this question is not clear. Thanks :D

Comment: Ask yourself, what is C1 doing? What is Q1 doing? What happens to Q2 when Q1 is switched on and off? Do the connections on Q2 make sense?

Comment: Your problem is C1. That will bock DC. Short that one out and flip R2 so it connects from base of Q2 to 12 V as a pull-up. You need a base resisotr on Q1 as well.

Comment: As I understand, you just want to control the 12V lamp with a 3.3V signal, right? Then, you just need a NPN and a resistor. Or you may use a mosfet (something like [that](http://jeelabs.org/2012/11/11/low-side-switching/)). But how did you come up with the above circuit? Where does it come from? What was your logic when designing it?

Comment: I've deleted the C1, shorted Q2-Emitter to ground, switch R2 into pull up resistor from Q2-base to 12V, and add 330 ohm res from SW1 to Q1-base. But still its not working

Comment: Did the bulb just dissappear from your circuit? As @dim said it, if you are fine with floating ground when the bulb is turned off, you can do it with just one NPN and a resistor.

Comment: @winny sorry, that bulb was a mistake. What does "floating ground" mean?

Comment: Floating ground is when you have the transistor under the load and you "cut" ground, making it an open circuit and the load is no longer powered. Having no ground but permanent plus connection will cause problems if that load is in turn connected elsewhere. A bulb is typically not connected elsewhere and hence it's very common to just go for a low side switch.

Comment: Well actually, the 12V source is output from buck converter, and 3.3V is output from MCU, what I try to create is controlling the buck output (on and off state). While in off-state, the buck output will stay at 0V, and while in on-state, the buck output is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your circuit, there are several strange placement of components. R1 and C1 is clearly wrong, also as mentioned in comment by @winny , you should have pull-up resistor to Q2 base. There are so many combination of transistor that can be used as a switch, you can try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI7VH8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Correct me if I'm wrong, but maybe here's some explanation:
R1 and R2 is used to limit base current, R3 as pull-up resistor,  and C1 to filter the output (optional)

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhI9O7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should do the trick.
I used the lightbulb as your load/output
and the switch(SW1) is now normal-closed
Q1 can also be a N-Channel Mosfet.

This should work like this:
SW1 is closed so Q1 is active and bring the gate of M1 to ground.
If SW1 is open Q1 is closed and the gate of M1 is on 12V

This is a low-cost-solution
Suggestions to improve this circuit are welcomed

Comment: What is C1 for?

Comment: C1 is for debouncing the switch.

Comment: Ok,I understand,well done.

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many things wrong with this circuit.  The most significant being that the load is connected across V2.  This means the circuit is not switching power to the load.  If Q2 ever did conduct it would be a short circuit (or very nearly so) across V2.  Again, the "switch" transistor is in parallel with V2.  I recommend you start over and use a Darlington pair for the switch, the basic concept is explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor

Comment: I'd like to post a regular comment for you (and Ben), but I don't have the rep, so I'll do it here:  What is the purpose of SW1?  In the text of the message, it says you want to control the output with the 3.3 volt signal.  Is that correct?